# Nestedscrollview scroll every other tabs

Tags: flutter, tabs, nestedscrollview

I'm using a Nestedscrollview on my application that have multiple tabs,

now the problem is:
Whenever I scroll down or up on one of my tabs the other tabs also scrolls down or up, is there a way to avoid this behavior?

thanks

There is my code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 5,
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
          SliverAppBar(
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            pinned: true,
            title: Text(
              'MyApp',
              style: GoogleFonts.cookie(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Search(),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
                iconSize: 25,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FeedScreen.routeName);
                },
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            bottom: TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.amber,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 17.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: myTabs,
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          
          EducationScreen(),
          FamilleScreen(),
          SportsScreen(),
          InfosScreen(),
          PolitiqueScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: I added my code snippet as you asked @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NestedScrollView` is the child and `TabBarView` is under it. Means every child is effected by same `NestedScrollView` that's why you are getting the same scroll position on every tab, You need to apply scrollable functionality on `TabBarView`'s `children`.

You can simply follow this widget.

```dart
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'MyApp',
            style: GoogleFonts.cookie(
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
              iconSize: 25,
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          bottom: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.amber,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: List.generate(5, (index) => Text("tab $index")),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
              5,
              (index) => SingleChildScrollView( // you can choose `CustomScrollView` for better 
                child: Container(
                  color: index.isEven ? Colors.green : Colors.cyanAccent,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                          44,
                          (y) => Container(
                                height: 100,
                                child: Text("tab $index item $y"),
                              ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```